# Почему не работает событие click

Tags: jquery, ajax

Скажем ответ от ajaxa:

```
    content = '<p><a href="#" data-id="'+value['post_id']+'" class="btn btn-primary read-more" role="button">Read more</a></p>'
 $('section').append(content);
```

и скажем после

```
 $('.read-more').click(function(){
        alert('ok');
});
```

то нифига не алертит(

//

Код целиком:

При клике по определенной категории, выводятся посты:

```
   $('.cat').click(function () {

            data = {id: $('a', this).data('id')};
            $.ajax({
                url: base_url + 'getContentByCategory',
                method: 'POST',
                data: data,
                success: function (response) {
                $('section').html('');
                    obj= JSON.parse(response);
                    $.each(obj, function(key, value){

content =  '<div class="row">' +
    '<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">' +
    '<div class="thumbnail">' +
    '<div class="caption">' +
    '<h3>'+value["tittle"]+'</h3>' +
    '<p>'+value["content"]+'</p>' +
    '<p class="read-more"><a href="#" data-id="'+value['post_id']+'" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Read more</a></p>' +
    '</div></div></div></div>';


                        $('section').append(content);
                    });

                }
            })
        });
```

После чего при нажатии кнопки read more, хочу чтобы открывался один пост, на тот который выбрали:

```
 $('.read-more').click(function(){
            alert('ok');

            data={post_id:$('a', this).data('id')};
            $.ajax({
                url: base_url + 'getSinglePost',
                method: 'POST',
                data: data,
                success: function (response) {
                    $('section').html('');
                    obj= JSON.parse(response);
                    $.each(obj, function(key, value){
                        console.log(value);
                        content= '<div class="page-header">'+
                            '<h1>'+value['tittle']+'</h1>'+
                                 '</div>'+
                                '<p>'+value['content']+'</p>';
                        $('section').append(content);
                    })
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Сам jquery подключен? Такая ошибка обычно бывает из-за отсутствия jquery.
 Проверьте пожалуйста инклуд jquery.
Ваш код полностью рабочий : [JsFiddle](http://bit.ly/1NagbXi)

Comment: Да, если просто скопировать эту строчку и вставить на html, то все работает, а вот после выхлопа ajaxa не работает, не понимаю почему.

Comment: Постарайтесь выложить код целиком.

Comment: если ajax изменяет DOM, где живёт ссылка, то это получается новая ссылка без событий. После ajax надо заново вешать обработчик, либо вешать на элемент-предок, который не меняется ajax-ом и проверять в обработчике, что сработало на ссылке, либо использовать $(document).on('click', '.read-more', handler). (Да и  вообще в jquery принято вешать обработчики событий через on: $('.read-more').on('click', handler))

Comment: Отлично! ) Помогли! Теперь все время буду через on)) Спасибо!